# Cannot Login to Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, login, domain

I was given a desktop computer that used to belong to a local bank in my town. However, I cannot use it because it used to be connected to a domain at the bank and now that it is at my house, it cannot connect to its domain. I was given the username and password but it does me no good since it is no longer connected. Is there any way I can remove this machine from its domain so I can login and use it as a personal computer here at my house?

Comment: I am utterly stunned that an institution like a bank would not only give away a working machine, un-wiped, but that they would actually hand out the login details too. Someone needs a) sacking & b) reporting to (i) the local authorities & (ii) the national newspapers.

Comment: My dad works there in the IT department. The pc was junked so he brought it home for me as a project piece.

Comment: I really don't think that is any excuse whatsoever. That is the most appalling breach of security.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm assuming that the computer is set to review credentials with a network before allowing you to log in.

I would at this point entering the computer in safe mode. They really should have formatted that information if the computer was given to you. The reason that they initially did that is because the computer is assuming that there is sensitive information on the drive that you should not have access to.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Doesn't commenting on a question require 50 reputation? "leave a comment below their posts"

Comment: Yes. See [Users with less than 50 reputation and "answers"](http://meta.superuser.com/q/4899)

Comment: I've read the document and don't see how that resolves this issue. When there is a question that has not yet been responded to I am not allowed to directly comment on the question. My only option is to "answer" the question and then comment on my own answer. If this is the case, you'll have to revise your information. I've seen others have expressed their frustration with this as well.